# How to test iOS push notifications using Detox

Tags: ios, react-native, integration-testing, detox

We've just implemented some custom handling for push notifications in our ReactNative mobile app, and I'm trying to write integration tests for these using Detox framework.
We know the notifications are working on real devices, however the notifications never are handled in detox tests.

```
const favoriteNotification = {
  "trigger": {
    "type": "push"
  },
  body: 'Your awesome notification',
};


describe(`Push Notifications`, () => {

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp({
      delete: true,
      newInstance: true,
      permissions: {notifications: 'YES'}
    });
    // code to login the user into the app
  });

  it(`app opened from the favorite notification`, async () => {
    await device.launchApp({
      // newInstance: true,
      // permissions: {notifications: 'YES'},
      userNotification: favoriteNotification
    });
    let element = element(by.text(favoriteNotification.body))
    await waitFor(element).toExist().withTimeout(5000);
    await expect(element).toExist();
  });

  it(`when app is in the foreground, should show an alert`, async () => {
    await device.launchApp({newInstance: true, permissions: {notifications: 'YES'}});

    await device.sendUserNotification(favoriteNotification);

    let element = element(by.text(favoriteNotification.body))
    await waitFor(element).toExist().withTimeout(5000);
    await expect(element).toExist();

  });
});
```

In both cases, absolutely nothing happens, and tests fail. Any idea how to make this work, or if it's even possible?

Detox version: 9.0.5

ReactNative version: 0.57.3

We're using `react-native-notifications` ver 1.1.20 to handle notifications. Perhaps this library is incompatible with detox mocking notifications? (I couldn't find any information to confirm/reject this though).

Comment: You cannot receive Push Notification alerts on the iOS Simulator, therefore this isn't feasible.

Comment: Detox allows for mocking push notifications: https://github.com/wix/detox/wiki/Mocking-User-Notifications-and-URLs and this is what I'm trying to achieve here. It's done on the iOS simulator, as they don't support running the tests on the real device in case of iOS as far as I know.

Comment: Hi @Magdalena! Did you ever figure this out? :)

Comment: @HenningHall No, I haven't! I've figured I'll try again when we upgrade to newest Detox version, however, I haven't gotten around to do it yet

Comment: Hi @Magdalena. Did you ever make progress on this? Figure it out?

Comment: @k.wahome We didn't figure it out on that version of Detox, and we haven't tried since (it wasn't working on detox 12 and react-native-notifications 1.5.0). I had a brief look at it though my understanding is that Detox uses the react-native-notifications library API to mock them, so these two need to be compatible - if you are on the latest versions, this should work... But again, I haven't confirmed it myself yet.

Comment: Thank you so much @Magdalena. I'll have a go with latest detox and react-native-notifications and see if that cuts it

Comment: Link changed - https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.MockingUserNotifications.md